# String to list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to split a string:

```
'QH QD JC KD JS'
```

into a list like:

```
['QH', 'QD', 'JC', 'KD', 'JS']
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How did you try to split the string?

Comment: I recommend you Google a free online book called "Dive Into Python"

Comment: Off-topic, but for search's sake : [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894283/812102).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
>>> 'QH QD JC KD JS'.split()
['QH', 'QD', 'JC', 'KD', 'JS']
```

[`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> Return a list of the words in the
>   string, using `sep` as the delimiter
>   string. If `maxsplit` is given, at most
>   `maxsplit` splits are done (thus, the
>   list will have at most `maxsplit+1`
>   elements). If `maxsplit` is not
>   specified, then there is no limit on
>   the number of splits (all possible
>   splits are made).
>
> If `sep` is given, consecutive
>   delimiters are not grouped together
>   and are deemed to delimit empty
>   strings (for example,
>   `'1,,2'.split(',')` returns `['1', '', '2']`). The `sep` argument may consist of
>   multiple characters (for example,
>   `'1<>2<>3'.split('<>')` returns `['1', '2', '3']`). Splitting an empty string
>   with a specified separator returns
>   `['']`.
>
> If `sep` is not specified or is `None`, a
>   different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive
>   whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain
>   no empty strings at the start or end
>   if the string has leading or trailing
>   whitespace. Consequently, splitting an
>   empty string or a string consisting of
>   just whitespace with a `None` separator
>   returns `[]`.
>
> For example, `' 1  2   3  '.split()`
>   returns `['1', '2', '3']`, and `'  1  2  3  '.split(None, 1)` returns `['1', '2 3  ']`.

Answer (score 25):

Here the simples

```
a = [x for x in 'abcdefgh'] #['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: Python 3.5 and later `[*'abcdefgh']`

Answer (score 14):

Maybe like this:

```
list('abcdefgh') # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you test your code on the give input 'QH QD JC KD JS' to see if it working properly

Comment: Not relevant to the question except its title, but helped when came from google :)

Answer (score 5):

Or for fun:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('[%s]'%','.join(map(repr,s.split())))
['QH', 'QD', 'JC', 'KD', 'JS']
>>>
```

**`ast.literal_eval`**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the split() function, which returns a list, to separate them.

```
letters = 'QH QD JC KD JS'

letters_list = letters.split()
```

Printing letters_list would now format it like this:

```
['QH', 'QD', 'JC', 'KD', 'JS']
```

Now you have a list that you can work with, just like you would with any other list. For example accessing elements based on indexes:

```
print(letters_list[2])
```

This would print the third element of your list, which is 'JC'