# Add characters (',') every time a certain character ( , )is encountered ? Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say you had a string

```
test = 'wow, hello, how, are, you, doing'
```

and you wanted

```
full_list = ['wow','hello','how','are','you','doing']
```

i know you would start out with an empty list:

```
empty_list = []
```

and would create a for loop to append the items into a list

i'm just confused on how to go about this,

I was trying something along the lines of:

```
for i in test:
    if i == ',':
```

then I get stuck . . .

Comment: This is a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453026/string-to-list-in-python

Comment: Upvotes for a question already asked a dozen times without having done any research?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, the nicest way to do what you want is

```
full_list = test.split(', ')
```

If your string might have some commas that aren't followed by spaces, you would need to do something a little more robust. Maybe

```
full_list = [x.lstrip() for x in test.split(',')]
```

Comment: Perhaps tack .lstrip() on the end to remove the spaces that follow the commas.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> test = 'wow, hello, how, are, you, doing'
>>> full_list = test.replace(",","','")
>>> print full_list
wow',' hello',' how',' are',' you',' doing
```

i just added the flanking quotations manually

Comment: This is a string that looks a bit like the _string representation_ of a list. A list is a very different thing to a string

Comment: Agreeing w/ @gnibbler : this answer has little to do with the question, -1.