# Python: convert string to list

Tags: python, string

I have the following string: 'keyword_1, keyword_2, keyword_3'

I want to convert the string into a list with each "keyword" being an element. So it would be: [keyword_1,keyword_2,keyword_3]

How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: `'keyword_1, keyword_2, keyword_3'.split(", ")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re    
re.compile(',\s*').split('keyword_1, keyword_2, keyword_3')
```

`split` on `,` and zero or more `space`.

Comment: That seems to put all 3 keywords into the first element.

Comment: try just `'keyword_1, keyword_2, keyword_3'.split(",")`

Comment: The `split` method on strings doesn't accept regex arguments.

Comment: Hmm...almost. The first element looks right ('keyword_1') but the subsequent elements still contain the space (' keyword_2)

Answer (score 3):

Use a list generator with `split` and `trim` like:

```
s = 'keyword_1, keyword_2, keyword_3'
[x.strip() for x in s.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [siplit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at most  maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not specified, then there is no limit on the number of splits (all possible splits are made).
>   If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example,  '1,,2'.split(',') returns ['1', '', '2']). The sep argument may consist of multiple characters (for example,  '1<>2<>3'.split('<>') returns ['1', '2', '3']). Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns  [''].
>   If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].

For example, ' 1  2   3  '.split() returns ['1', '2', '3'], and '  1  2  3  '.split(None, 1) returns ['1', '2 3  '].

&& [String to list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453026/string-to-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import additional modules, you could do something like this:

```
string = 'keyword_1, keyword_2, keyword_3'
string = string.split(",")
for i in range(len(string)):
    string[i] = string[i].strip()
```