# Function to convert a string to a tuple

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, tuples

Here is an example of what data I will have:

```
472747372 42 Lawyer John Legend Bishop
```

I want to be able to take a string like that and using a function convert it into a tuple so that it will be split like so:

```
"472747372" "42" "Lawyer" "John Legend" "Bishop"
```

NI Number, Age, Job, surname and other names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453026/string-to-list-in-python)

Comment: Where did "John Legend" and "Bishop" come from and how do you determine "John Legend" should be a single string instead of split out?

Answer (score 0):

In python, `str` has a built-in method called `split` which will split the string into a list, splitting on whatever character you pass it. It's default is to split on whitespace, so you can simply do:

```
my_string = '472747372 42 Lawyer Hermin Shoop Tator'
tuple(my_string.split())
```

EDIT: After OP changed the post.

Assuming there will *always* be an NI Number, Age, Job, and surname, you would have to do:

```
elems = my_string.split()
tuple(elems[:3] + [' '.join(elems[3:5])] + elems[5:])
```

This will allow you to support an arbitrary number of "other" names after the surname

Comment: I think `'472747372', '42', 'Lawyer', 'Hermin', 'Shoop', 'Tator'` != `"472747372" "42" "Lawyer" "Hermin Shoop" "Tator"`.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I then make sure the other names such as "John" and "Legend" in the example get put together. Thank you

Comment: `"John"` and `"Legend"` aren't in the input though?

Comment: @NLee57 Updated the response.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
>>> string = "472747372 42 Lawyer John Legend Bishop"
>>> string.split()[:3] + [' '.join(string.split()[3:5])] + [string.split()[-1]]
['472747372', '42', 'Lawyer', 'John Legend', 'Bishop']
```

Or:

```
>>> string.split(maxsplit=3)[:-1] + string.split(maxsplit=3)[-1].rsplit(maxsplit=1)
['472747372', '42', 'Lawyer', 'John Legend', 'Bishop']
```

Comment: Thanks man. Can you explain to me how the second piece of code you typed splits the string so that John and Legend are together?