# How to convert string into list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have string as:

```
myString = 'example'
```

How can I convert it into a list as :

```
lst = ['example']
```

in an efficient way?

Comment: either `[s]` or `s.split()` when `s='example'`. Although `s.split()` is much slower.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453026/string-to-list-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

The most natural way is correct:

```
mystr = 'example'
lst = [mystr]
```

Also, don't name your variables `str`; it overrides the built-in `str`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the append() function to achieve that:

```
lst = []
str = 'example'

lst.append(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

`str='example'`

```
l=list(str)
```

Now l will contain ['e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e']