# How to make the whole string a list element?

Tags: python, list

I have a question about converting a string to a list. I know the following:

```
>>str1 - "123"
>>list(string)
['1','2','3']
```

but how to output:

```
['123']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string into list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54396086/how-to-convert-string-into-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use braces directly:

`[str1]`

Or if you want to stick with `list`:

`list((str1,))`

does the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
list1 = [str1]
```

Answer (score 0):

its easy

```
>>>str1 = "123"
>>>"".join(str1)
['123']
```

or: `[str1]`

Comment: Your first answer isn't true, try to run the ```type``` command on the result.
From the documentation:
str.join(iterable)
Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.