# How to split input of numbers into a list

Tags: python

How do I turn these numbers into a list using python?

16 3 2 13 -> ["16","3","2","13"]

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66166103/edit) your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more tips about this site and asking questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String to list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453026/string-to-list-in-python)

Comment: What format does `16 3 2 13` represent?  Did you mean to type `"16 3 2 13"` to indicate a single string?

Answer (score 1):

You can divide it by using [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split):

```
"16 3 2 13".split()
```

Output:

```
["16","3","2","13"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to split by whitespaces.

```
data = '16 3 2 13'
print(data.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '16 3 2 13'

b = ['']
print(type(b))
print(len(b))

j = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != ' ':
        b[j] = b[j] + a[i]
    else:
        j = j+1
        b.append('')

print(b)
```